# How to port a SIM card to an Android phone

Tags: sim-card, data-plan, sim-unlocking

The procedure for porting a SIM card from a pay-as-you-go phone to an iPhone 4 is well documented ([example 1](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/05/convert-unused-iphone-pay-phone-jailbreaking-unlocking-required), [example 2](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/01/prepaid-iphone-setup-iphone-for-pay-as-you-go-plan/), [config tool for iOS 5](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)). This is a nice option for people mostly on WiFi who use a small number of minutes (or VoIP), because with AT&T GoPhone plans, you can keep network costs down toward $100/year.

Is there a similar procedure for porting to a high-end Android phone? For example, can you buy a $3 GoPhone from Best Buy, buy an unlocked or AT&T Samsung Galaxy S II off eBay, move the SIM card into the Galaxy, and expect it to work? Other than ensuring the GoPhone plan has a data bundle feature, what other configuration is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an unlocked phone, I don't think there should be any problem. The SIM card for GoPhone is apparently just a regular prepaid SIM card and is not tied to the phone it is sold with. If the phone doesn't recognize the APN for 3G, just go to `Settings > Wireless and Networks > Mobile Networks > Access point Names` and enter the appropriate access point settings manually.

Comment: If the phone is locked to AT&T, would that work, too?

Comment: @EdwardBrey: A SIM locked phone is locked to its original SIM card.